# Authentication set username kotlin Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, kotlin

I have a problem when I try to add a username to a new user profil. The registration works fine, but I can't set the username.

My database:

[image: firestore database]

my user class:

data class User(var username: String = "")

Here is my code:

class createUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var firestoreDB: FirebaseFirestore
private var newUsername: User? = null
private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
//lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user)
    firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

//Button how create a new user
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val createNewUser = findViewById<Button>(R.id.New_User_Button)
    createNewUser.setOnClickListener {
        registerUser ()
    }
}

//New user function
private fun registerUser () {
    val emailTxt = findViewById(R.id.new_user_Email) as EditText
    val passwordTxt = findViewById(R.id.new_user_Password) as EditText
    val nameTxt = findViewById(R.id.new_user_Username) as EditText

    var email = emailTxt.text.toString()
    var password = passwordTxt.text.toString()
    var name = nameTxt.text.toString()


    if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !name.isEmpty()) {
        mAuth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = mAuth?.currentUser
                    val uid = user!!.uid
                    name = newUsername?.username.toString()
                    firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).set(name)
                    startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully registered :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error registering, try again later :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please fill up the Credentials :|", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

println(name)
    }

}

Comment: What do you mean through "but I can't set the username."?

Comment: @Alexander Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
val username = User(name)
firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).set(username)
```

You need to initialize `firestoreDB`, `lateinit` basically means initialize later, also it seems that the `users` is a collection and not a document according to your image.

Comment: Mm I see, but I still get the same problem. do you have any suggestions

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: When I set a println on the varible ”name” I can see it in the Logcat. But when I set a println to ”newUsername?.username.toString()” is says null.
But I still not see anything in my database. So the problem are same, no connecting to my database. I have updated my code.

Comment: this `newUsername?.username.toString()` is null because `newUsername` is null.. `newUsername` is of type `User` did you set the `username`? `newUsername = User(); newUsername?.username = "peter"`?

Comment: Yes like this: "private var newUsername: User? = null". But the problem is still that I do not see it in the database. because I should see a null sign in my database if it was connected to my database? Or I'am wrong?

Comment: u need to initialize it, like this `newUsername = User()` then you need to set the username like this `newUsername?.username = "peter"` then you can add

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213090/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-alexander).